# How do I have the "11" in =TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,E3),C6:C11),,1) dynamic so it automatically is the last row in a list that is a non-zero?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sequence

I have a list that will vary in size based on the number of names in a different column. I currently have the formula =TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,E3),C6:C11),,1) in which C6:C11 is looking up on the list that will change in size based on the number of names I have. I need the "11" to automatically change to the last non-zero row in column C.

I tried doing =+TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,E3),indirect("C6:C"&MAX(IF(C6:C72=0,0,ROW(C6:C72)))),,1) however I am getting the error that I entered too many arguments.

Comment: Can there be 0's in a list between other values?

Answer (score 0):

Right syntax would be:

```
=TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,E3),INDIRECT("C6:C"&MAX(IF(C6:C72=0,0,ROW(C6:C72))))),,1)
```

If there are no 0's in a list that needs to be repeated, you could simply filter out zero values with `FILTER(C6:C72,C6:C72<>0)`. Use it instead of range `C6:C72`:

```
=TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,E3),FILTER(C6:C72,C6:C72<>"")),,1)
```